# using try catch block in webservice and sending the result in angularjs controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, try-catch

i am creating a web app in which i am updating the records with web service and then sending the email to the particular person from another method in web service

for ex

i have two methods

1 for update

2 for sending mail

```
    public void updcomson(string Id, string upddate, string updcomname, string updbrandname, string updzone, string updlocation, string updstartime, string updendtime, string updprogram, string updvenue, string updvenuename, string pm, string pax)
    {
    //updating
    SendEmailsms();
    con.Close();
    var json = js.Serialize(message);
    Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "message" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
    }
```

> SendEmailsms();

this line is calling the second method

in my second method i am calling a stored procedure which looks like this

```
   // automail store procedure email send dynamically
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sonvinmailsmssend", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brandname", brandname.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zone", zone.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property", property.ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

but sometimes there are multiple records save with the same name in my database so i get the error

> subquery returns more then 1 value

i just want to use try catch block here

like

```
try
{

       // automail store procedure email send dynamically
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sonvinmailsmssend", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brandname", brandname.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zone", zone.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property", property.ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
}

catch
{
//what i need to write here??
}
```

what i need to do in my controller??

```
$http.get('/csuv5.asmx/updcomson', {
            params: {
                //params
            }
        })

        .then(function (response) {
```

//what i need to do here?
            });

Comment: make the name uniqe and add a field for the nonunique name?

Comment: what do you want to return , or what do you want to do if it catches an exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service:
you need to change return type of your updcomson to list or Dictionary

```
 public List<string> updcomson(string Id, string upddate, string updcomname, string updbrandname, string updzone, string updlocation, string updstartime, string updendtime, string updprogram, string updvenue, string updvenuename, string pm, string pax)
    {
    //updating
    string errMessage  = SendEmailsms();
    con.Close();
    var json = js.Serialize(message);
    Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "message" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");

        List<string> plist = new List<string>();
        plist.Add(errMessage); 
        return plist;
    }
```

//Exception block of SendEmailSMS(), change return type to string from void

```
catch(Exception ex){
 // return the message you want to 
 return ex.Message;
}
```

Angular: something like this

```
$http.get('/csuv5.asmx/updcomson', {
            params: {
                //params
            }
        })

        .then(function (response) { 
$scope.returnMessage= response.data;     
//now you have your returned value in $scope.returnMessage, use it in alert or to show in a label as error
});
```

//////
small example from my code
/////

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Login/Authenticate")]
        public bool isAuthenticate(LoginVal val)
        {
            bool auth = false;
            using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
            {
                PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                if (ctx.ValidateCredentials (val.UserID, val.Password))
                {
                    auth = true;
                }
            }
            return auth;
        }
    }
```

Angular:

```
var LoginApp = angular.module('LoginApp',[]);

LoginApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.LoginAuth = function ()
    {
        var dataToPost = {
            'UserID': $("#txtUserid").val(),
            'Password': $("#txtPassword").val()
        }

        var url = 'http://localhost:52212/api/Login/Authenticate';

        $http.post(url, dataToPost).then(function (response) {
            $scope.isAuth = response.data;
            if ($scope.isAuth) {
                //$window.location.href = 'Index.html';
                $window.location.href = 'customscripts/js/Index.html';
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Wrong Username/Password");
                //$window.location.href = 'Login.html';
                $window.location.href = 'customscripts/js/Login.html';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return an IHttpActionResult from your controller:

```
//C# controller
//You also need to inherit your controller from ApiConroller 
// public class MyController : ApiConroller {//the code...}


  public void updcomson(string Id, string upddate, string updcomname, string updbrandname, string updzone, string updlocation, string updstartime, string updendtime, string updprogram, string updvenue, string updvenuename, string pm, string pax)
{
  try{
    //do work...
    return OK(myResult);
  }
  catch(){
   return NotFound();
  }
}
```

Angular service:

```
$http.get('/csuv5.asmx/updcomson', {
            params: {
                //params
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) { 
          // do something with the response
        },function(error){
          // handle error
         })
```